# onclick not working for Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension for Google Chrome, and onclick method does not seem to be working. I have an html file popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Before clicking button</p>
<button type="button" id="thing">Pls work</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And JavaScript file popup.js:

```
var a =0;
function myFunction()
{
    a= a +1;
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent=a;
}
document.getElementById('thing').onclick = myFunction();
```

And, finally, a manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "shark.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

When I load this extension onto Chrome and then click on the extension, it presents an extension window that goes straight to saying "1", rather than the message "Before clicking button." Then, when I try to click the button, nothing happens- that is, the text remains 1, and does not increment like it should.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

JS:

```
 window.onload = function() {
    var a =0;
    function myFunction()
    {
        a= a +1;
        document.getElementById('demo').textContent=a;
    }
    document.getElementById('thing').onclick = myFunction;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo">Before clicking button</p>
<button type="button" id="thing">Pls work</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it suits your needs, You could up vote the answer and set the question as answered..

Answer (score 0):

The only think that needs to change is

```
document.getElementById('thing').onclick = myFunction();
```

to

```
document.getElementById('thing').onclick = myFunction;
```

The first on executes the function instead of setting the function to execute for the onclick event.